# How to get the distance of a route using Bing maps API?

Tags: javascript, documentation, bing-maps

The "function" that I need is in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/modules/directions-module/routesummary-object), but there is not a code example, just "RouteSummary Object" and the bellow there is the "distance", which is what I need.

I got the code bellow in [this link](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/directionscreatedrivingroute#JS)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
        
        <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function loadMapScenario() {
                var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    /* No need to set credentials if already passed in URL */
                    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.606209, -122.332071),
                    zoom: 12
                });
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
                    var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
                    // Set Route Mode to driving
                    directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });
                    var waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Redmond', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.67683029174805, -122.1099624633789) });
                    var waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: 'Seattle', location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.59977722167969, -122.33458709716797) });
                    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
                    directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);
                    // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered
                    directionsManager.calculateDirections();
                   
                });
                
            }
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=AnOeSZ6a7LgcnBLVjmZ4xfQWIWZjzKv7bDwgyRk-W4NlkGnZGQdk5atUjsunU5yH&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried like that ways:

```
routeSummary.distance();
```

and too:

```
directionsManager.routeSummary.distance();
```

I don't know almost anything about JavaScript and don't know how to read documentation.

after all, how do I use an Object like described in the documentation?
I just want to know what mean by "object" in this case, is the class-related object of OOP or not?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Since you are new, I highly recommend that you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One thing that improves your question a look would be if you provide a code example of what you are working on, or what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thx, fixed, that's better?

Comment: Yes! Based on your question, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/directions-module-examples/directions-module-events) should help you. Take especially a close look at function ```directionsUpdated```. HTH.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just saved my final course work

Comment: I don't know if this is a good or a bad thing :). Please consider adding your solution as an answer (below) and marking it as the correct solution. The code you provide should be runnable - ideally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event to the directions manager since the route calculation is done asynchronously. Here is an example:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', directionsUpdated);

function directionsUpdated(e) {
    //Get the current route index.
    var routeIdx = directionsManager.getRequestOptions().routeIndex;

    //Get the distance of the route.
    var distance = .routeSummary[routeIdx].distance;

}
```